# Is this bacteria or fungi?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, mycology

I've been growing bacteria on an agar plate and after putting the dishes in the incubator, this is what I saw. I'm new to bacteria identification, and is this just contamination by fungi or is this actually bacteria colonies? I suppose it is fungi, but what about the white, round white circles on top of the fungi(the top, left picture), is that bacteria colonies?

[image: Picture of fungi?]

Comment: Well what did you put on the plate? Currently it's extremely hard to answer because we know very little about your experimental protocol.

Comment: @rg255 I put my thumb on the plate, to see the amount of bacteria on it to then compare the amount with after washing the hand using different methods. I suppose the plate may have been contaminated from the air because of insufficient sterile technique.

Comment: How about a side view? Do you see spores in the stalks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably mostly fungal contamination if you did not sterilize and left the container open. This video on how to isolate bacteria better may help: https://www.jove.com/video/3064/aseptic-laboratory-techniques-plating-methods

Good luck!